# Converting a double pointer to single pointer and vice-versa

Tags: c, pointers

argv holds the command line args which is a double pointer. I need to pass this to a function which accepts a single pointer as the parameter.
How do I do this? Just typecast it?

Comment: Depends on what the function's argument means, but a cast is definitely the wrong move.

Comment: `argv` is an array of arguments. Do you need to pass all arguments as single string?

Comment: How about using argv[i] as a single pointer to the "ith" parameter?

Comment: @justanothercoder yes i need to pass all arguments as a single string...

Answer (score 2):

A double pointer in `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers. Each pointer inside that array represents a single null-terminated C string.

If another function expects a single pointer, it is probably expecting a single null-terminated C string, not a whole array. That is why casting is not going to produce the expected result: you need to pick which of the parameters you wish to pass, and then pass `argv[index]`, which would be a single pointer.

Above, `index` represents the position of the parameter that you are passing to your function. It must be between 0, inclusive, and `argc`, exclusive.

Comment: it won't be efficient...right?

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey What do you mean? `argv[index]` is as efficient as it gets - a single CPU instruction on most modern platforms.

Comment: i was thinking that i need to loop through the argv for extracting the data, that's why...but thanks I think I can fix it.